# Running C++ exe using Process.Start versus wrapping the C++ code using CLR

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr

I have a C++ executable which I need to integrate into my .NET app. The C++ exe is a specialized calculator which will be invoked very frequently during lengthy processing of some large data. For this, I need the integration to be as efficient as possible.

In term of efficiency, is there any advantage of wrapping the C++ code into a CLR .dll which I can then use directly from my .NET app over just using Process.Stat and parsing the output stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Process.Start() it is creating a new application, allcation of memory and task scheduling is an overehead. given the fact that you are calling it many times, you should make it into a DLL and use the function. as the loaded DLL will always be in memory and run faster.

lets say that there is change in the parameter to the exe, you might not catch it soon enough, if it is packaged in a DLL then its more controlled. contracts are stronger.

Comment: What if we use Process.Start() once, and then just WriteLine to the inputstream every time we need a result? Is the overhead of stream noticeable when both the applications are in memory?

Comment: @Vlad it's important to understand when to use Process.Start. ideally if you own the code to the exe, its important that you write a dll and then use the dll in your front end application or .net application. its not about the overhead that is needed to run using process start but the fact that you have much greater control over the code.

mistakes like wrong parameters and return types and exceptions can be better handled if you are using DLL's.

Answer (score 1):

Launching a separate process involves creating a lot of overhead for that process and it's threads. It also will be loaded/unloaded in memory every time. A dll could be loaded into memory once, and executed many times all on the main thread. So there is definitely efficiency to be gained by going the dll route. Whether or not it's REALLY worth it is a trade-off between how much work it is to wrap it in the dll, and how much efficiency you will truly gain.

You said that it will be called frequently. If this means thousands of times, it will probably be worth putting into a dll. But really, measurement is the only way to know for sure how much difference it will make.

Comment: Additionally, going the DLL route will get rid of the overhead of parsing, since you should be able to send and receive native datatypes to/from the DLL functions.